# Fetching Location on Different Devices Mainly from Chinese Manufacturers

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, locationmanager

**Use Case No. 1**

You have a device that came from Chinese Manufacturers and you want to get the current position of the device. As per @mvanbeusekom says in GitHub, because of the war between Trump and Chinese Manufacturers, some of the devices doesn't have the full functionality of Google Play Services, so you will resort in using the `LocationManager`:

```
Position _currentPosition;
_currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition(
  desiredAccuracy: Location.high,
  forceAndroidLocationManager: true
);
```

**Use Case No. 2.**

You have a device manufactured by Chinese and have used the first solution, but still, the plugin won't return the current position of the device. Before moving on, there are two scenarios in which I had experienced the capabilities of the first solution; (1) when you are indoors. (2) when you are outdoors.

**Use Case No 2.1 - Indoors**

Upon researching (correct me if I'm wrong) the `LocationManager` in `geolocator` uses the `GPS_PROVIDER` by default. But when I did this:

```
Position _currentPosition;
_currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition(
  desiredAccuracy: Location.medium,
  forceAndroidLocationManager: true
);
```

I now have the current position of the device but not that accurate because obviously I have set the accuracy to `medium`.

**Use Case No. 2.2 - Outdoors**

Now, all of the above solutions are working outdoors, either setting the `desiredAccuracy` to `Location.high` or to `Location.medium`.

**Use Case No.3**
Based on my experiences I have therefore concluded that setting the `desiredAccuracy` to `Location.medium` and setting the `forceAndroidLocationManager` to `true` is my best shot. But when I tried this to non-Chinese variant devices it won't return the current position. So, I changed the `desiredAccuracy` to `Location.high`. Now it worked again but not with the Chinese variant devices. I had to wait for almost 10 minutes in order for the app to get the current position.

Before trying these approaches please remember to add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**Problem:**

I've been testing my app on a Chinese Device because nowadays in our country (Philippines) the number of Chinese device users is increasing because of its affordable price. I cannot find a way to get the current location without relying on `geolocator`.

**Disclaimer**

The above use cases are based on my experience with the `geolocator` and may not be of help to you. But if you have an idea or a solution to this, please help me.